# iOS launch image in simulator but not in test flight

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add a launch image to my app which is purely a UIwebview based app. I get the launch image on the simulator (iPhone 7) but not in test flight (iPad pro).
I followed some guides and removed the laud storyboard file, ticked every orientation and requires full screen. Any suggestions on what is causing the problem. I added all images in the assets.xcassets launch image catalogue.

Comment: Are your images added to the project o are they just a link?

Comment: They are dragged into the project same way as the icons and they are in the assets folder.

Comment: have you tried ipad pro on the simulator to verify that it's not just a problem with the icons for ipad pro?

Comment: Yes and I also works fine as on the iPhone 7 simulator.

Comment: Have you deleted the app on your device prior to testing a new version of the app?

Comment: That did the trick but it only shows for like one second. Can I set a timeframe in the launch screen?